# Hibernate logging in console with WARN HHH000174

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a system with Hibernate 4.1.7 and Spring 1.3.4 jpa. When I run `myEntity.findOne(id)`, the hibernate WARN logging in console:

> [main]; WARN; org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer; -
>   HHH000174: Function template anticipated four arguments, but arguments
>   first encountered.

Find out about some possible solutions in but could not solve my problem in http://jira.xwiki.org/browse/XWIKI-9215, https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6280.

I am checking the code  logging in `org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer`

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "UnusedDeclaration" })
    public String render(List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) {
        int numberOfArguments = args.size();
        if ( getAnticipatedNumberOfArguments() > 0 && numberOfArguments != getAnticipatedNumberOfArguments() ) {
            LOG.missingArguments( getAnticipatedNumberOfArguments(), numberOfArguments );
        }
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int i = 0; i < chunks.length; ++i ) {
            if ( i < paramIndexes.length ) {
                final int index = paramIndexes[i] - 1;
                final Object arg =  index < numberOfArguments ? args.get( index ) : null;
                if ( arg != null ) {
                    buf.append( chunks[i] ).append( arg );
                }
            }
            else {
                buf.append( chunks[i] );
            }
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
```

Comment: answer posted for your acceptance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all good research

Yes, this was raised as a bug earlier with `Hibernate`, and was provided with a fix also. But due to lack of test cases, it was rejected and never released as a part of subsequent releases.

The bug was introduced as a part of `Hibernate 3.6`.

So still needs to wait for somebody to raise the ticket, and provide suitable test cases and fix.

refer [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5676) for more details.

Comment: it is help me =)

Comment: I also see this and it seems to be the case that for JPQL functions like "trim" for example, Hibernate expects the maximum allowed number of arguments (4 in the case of trim) and logs this warning when you use a (totally acceptable) version of the function e.g. just trim(' string '). Would be very much appreciated if anyone working on Hibernate could re-open that ticket or file a new one. Test case shouldn't be too difficult to craft I expect, but I myself can't right now for lack of time and setup :(

Answer (score 2):

The referenced (root cause) hibernate bug [HHH-5676](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5676) was rejected so I expect no improvement in the near future with this WARNING.

There is a way to switch it off at least if it annoys you. You can restrict the logging level of the hibernate class TemplateRenderer to ERROR. The class TemplateRenderer does this log and (at this time) this is the only logging in that class. It depends on your logger how to do it. In my case:

```
logger.org.hibernate.dialect.function.TemplateRenderer.level=ERROR
```

Hiding this is risky because of obvious reasons. Do it carefully!